# Doubt in the derivation of the relation between Young's modulus and Modulus of rigidity

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]

Please refer to the image attached.

My doubt is marked in red. What i don't understand in this part of the derivation is that how and why is the extension and compression is equivalent to a shear theta? and if there is a theta where is it being formed?? Also there is compression along x axis given by -F/Y -σF/Y = -F/Y(1+σ) (where σ is poisson ratio). But in the place where i have marked in red that compression sign (which is negative) have been converted to positive sign, How so? and why?

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange, RiRi. Please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) in this site.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a smaller (horizontal) square with its vertices at the four points where the force vectors contact the cube (at the center of the four faces).  This is the shape of the square prior to loading.  Now imagine that, when the forces are applied, the square deforms into a rhombus, with one of its diagonals increasing by the strain in the x direction and its other diagonal decreasing by an equal compressive strain in the y direction.  The angle of the vertex decreases from 90 degrees to the new included angle of the rhombus.  This change in angle, in radians, is the shear strain.